# deny from all htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When use combination

```
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

with following

```
RewriteEngine off

    <Files 1.php>
        Order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1</Files>
    <Files 2.php>
        Order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Files>
    <Files 3.php>
        Order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Files>
```

**I've 500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: Which version of apache are you using?

Comment: I don't know how to know ?

Comment: Ok here's my apache version 2.2.31

Comment: Please check your Apache logs. You can also [try the directives in reverse](/a/1281282/1626250).